# ftp zip files from one server to another

Tags: php, ftp

I am attempting to transfer a zip file via ftp from one server to mine, so that I can use the data in the file to update my database table.  Here is my ftp.php file:

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$date = "2013-05-21-11-19-40";
$ftp_server="ftp.server.com";
$ftp_user_name="BookCellar";
$ftp_user_pass="*****";
$file = "/reports/other/compreport_abebooks_" .$date. ".zip";//tobe uploaded
$remote_file = "/chroot/home/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/compreport_abebooks_" .$date. ".zip"; 

?>
```

and my ftpUpload.php file is:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
require_once('ftp.php');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);//ftp_connect

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
// check connection
if ((! $conn_id ) || (! $login_result )) {
echo "FTP connection has failed!" ;
exit;

} else {
echo "Connected for user $ftp_user_name" ;
}

ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/');

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
exit;
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
exit;
}
echo $php_errormsg;
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

When I run these I get the error messge:

```
    [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/ftpUpload.php on line 25
```

Line 25 is:

```
    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY)) {
```

I have researched a bunch of other posts on SO and have not found a solution.  My connection works, but I can't get the file to transfer.
How do I (if even possible) get this to transfer to my server?

EDIT: Am I missing the fact that I need to connect not only to their server($file) AND my server ($remote_file)????

Comment: have you checked that both `$file` and `$remote_file` are valid and have the right paths? Does your PHP user have the right permissions to read the local file?

Comment: I can verify the paths on the servers themselves.  $file is on one server and $remote_file is on mine.  Both are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a path to the destination file

```
$remote_file = "/chroot/home/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/compreport_abebooks_" .$date. ".zip";
```

e.g. - this doesn't work

```
ftp_put($conn, '/www/site/file.html','c:/wamp/www/site/file.html',FTP_BINARY);
```

you have to put

```
<?php
ftp_chdir($conn, '/www/site/');
ftp_put($conn,'file.html', 'c:/wamp/www/site/file.html', FTP_BINARY );
```

A FTP server hides his absolute path `/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/`

All folders must be relative to the `root`

```
ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/testbcos/accounting/');
```

test the result of ftp_chdir ! Are your in the right directory ?

```
echo ftp_pwd($conn_id);
```

Try to connect to the FTP server via a browser.

```
ftp://BookCellar@ftp.server.com
```

What you get is `/` the `root`. Folders and files that you see in the browser, are below the `root` directory.

**Update :** A working out of the box example.

the `$password =` line must be replaced with [Download pass](http://moskito-x.de/stack/files/pass.txt)

ftp.php

```
<?php
    $password = "????";
    $resource = ftp_connect('ftp.strato.com');
    $login = ftp_login($resource, 'ftp_mx_all@moskito-x.de', $password);
    $list = ftp_rawlist($resource, '/');
    print_r($list);
?>
```

You will get with print_r

`Array ( [0] => drwxr-xr-x 2 ftp ftp 4096 May 23 20:15 aFolder [1] => -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 167 May 23 20:25 tutorial.txt )`

we can see there is a folder `aFolder` and a file `tutorial.txt`.
We are interest what files are in the folder `aFolder` ?
So replace the $list = with

```
$list = ftp_rawlist($resource, '/aFolder');
```

and run the php script again. The output :

`Array ( [0] => drwxr-xr-x 3 ftp ftp 4096 May 23 19:24 .. [1] => -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 167 May 23 20:25 tutorial.txt [2] => -rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 271 May 23 21:16 tutorial.zip )`

Now we want to download `aFolder/tutorial.txt` .
Add following below `print_r($list);` .

```
     echo "<br />\n";
     $local_file = "tmp.txt" ;
     $file = ftp_get($resource, $local_file, '/aFolder/tutorial.txt',FTP_ASCII);
      if ($file) {
         echo "$local_file has been successfully written\n";
     } else {
         echo "An error has occurred\n";
     }
```

The Output :

[image]

The folder where the php script is has changed.

[image]

now there is a new file `tmp.txt` !

If you bring this little script to run. We can go further.

**From our chat :**
Your server does not allow a ftp call to a url.

look `allow_url_fopen = ON`

```
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');

if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
}

echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

Then try it again.

Comment: @Jim : What do you get in a Browser with : `ftp://BookCellar@ftp.server.com`

Comment: I get a connection time out error when I put it in as is.  Do I need to replace ftp.server.com with login info?

Comment: @Jim : Of course you need the "ftp.server.com", replace with your FTP server address.

Comment: I get this:  550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel

Comment: 1st one my connection times out, second it doesn't find the server.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I modified my script to reflect yours, and there is no output for print_r($list).  I know there is a file there because I can transfer it with FileZilla, and extract it.  I am going to have to contact the site to see what permissions they have set for me.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @Jim : Have you tested without any change to get to my ftp-server ? The password is 2 hours available . Link in my answer. This must work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30577/discussion-between-jim-and-moskito-x)

Answer (score 2):

```
set_time_limit(0);
exec("wget --continue http://example.com/site.zip");
exit;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In the first excerpt change the remote tile to be

```
`$remote_file = "compreport_abebooks_" .$date. ".zip";`
```

prior to the put you are changing into the directory.

Also note that the directory that you reference in the `ftp_chdir` call differs from the one in the $remote_file referenced at the top.

```
 /home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/
```

vs

```
 /chroot/home/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/
```

Comment: I have made the suggested changes, and verified the path in the servers error logs, however i am still getting the error message.  Do I need the back ticks like you have it or was that just to show the difference?

Comment: @Jim - does it matter that `$remote_file`'s path starts with `/chroot/`? Have you tried running the same set of commands using command line FTP to see if that generates any errors?

Comment: @andrewsi didn't notice that i missed it in my answer has been updated

Comment: I have tried it without the /chroot/ and with it.  when I run $file = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'compreport_abebooks_2013-05-21-11-19-40.zip';
echo $file; it shows the /chroot/.  I can download teh file using filezilla with no problems, but I want to automate this